# Blender 2.79 png Label on glass to be renderend on Blend4web

Tags: texturing, uv, blend4web

I'd like to put a .png image on a glass plane I've created then render it through Blend4web;
I've used Uv  but I couldn't figure out why I can't see the glass texture on Blend4web.
Can u please help me out?

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivz4y.png)
[image]

Comment: Solved, now i would like to know if is it possible to avoid Blender scaling images when uv mapping

Comment: Don’t do that. Ask a separate question, and Mark this as solved.